# OpenCV iOS Drawing Bounding Box

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm trying to draw a box around a foot in a photo. I can do it with other objects, including ones that aren't fully in the image (I have pasted my code below). However, when I try to use it with a foot, it draws the contour perfectly but the rectangle is always the around the full image. I have attached pictures below of the result. Is there any way to change my code to fix this, or is there any other method possible of drawing a box around the foot?

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfPF8.jpg)

[Contour and Bounding Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDWHT.jpg)

```
RNG rng(12345);
Mat threshold_output;
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

Mat srcImage;
UIImageToMat(image, srcImage);
cvtColor(srcImage, srcImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
blur(srcImage, srcImage, cv::Size(3,3));

threshold(srcImage, threshold_output, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );


vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
vector<cv::Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );

for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
    approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
}

Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    if (contourArea(contours[i]) < 1000) {
        continue;
    }
    Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
    drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point());
    rectangle(drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
    cout << "Height:" << boundRect[i].height << " Width: " << boundRect[i].width << endl;
}

return MatToUIImage(drawing);
```

Comment: Hello @jacob Perks you need to go through this here they make rectangle around the car. may be you got reference from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044853/opencv-draw-rectangles-around-only-large-contours OR https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the bottom part of the foot reaches the image boundary, the contour seems to wrap around the perimeter of the image and thereby create a large bounding box that includes the entire image.

A quick and dirty solution will be to set the border pixels of the image to zero before applying `findContours()`. For a better solution, you have to think about the actual problem that you are trying to solve.